# Cookies must be enabled past this point in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, windows, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I am trying to use phpMyAdmin with WAMP server.

I am just doing a delete query, but in phpMyAdmin I am given an error like this:

> cookies must be enabled past this point.

I am using apache v2.2 and PHP v5.4.3.

Please could you help me to over come this.

Comment: which OS you are using

Comment: There is a duplicate [Server Fault answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/128341/can-not-login-to-phpmyadmin-cookies-must-be-enabled-past-this-point/145720). My problem was blocked localhost cookies in Firefox - quite why they suddenly got blocked I don't know.

Answer (score -1):

Edit:

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'Your blowfish secret here'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

Comment: This is an exact copy of a previous [Server Fault answer](http://serverfault.com/a/201850/51312)

Comment: N.B. I've just edited the other answer, so they'll be different now